# Meaning of "2 got message" lines in Opera's JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, opera, opera-dragonfly

When I'm debugging JavaScript code in Opera browser, the console is always displaying messages with the **Info** icon  labelled as "2 got message" in the JavaScript tab:

```
2 got message        Event thread: message        Event thread: message
2 got message        Event thread: message        Event thread: message
2 got message        Event thread: message        Event thread: message
```

There's nothing clickable on them and I've unable to find a single Google result.

What do these info lines mean?

Comment: Could it be window.postMessage, e.g., in a frame? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: @Boldewyn - The code is not using it, not at least on purpose. I couldn't find the `postMessage` string in the source code.

Comment: maybe there are `console.info` calls ?

Comment: are you getting anything similar in WebInspector or Firebug ? // have you tried step-by-step execution of scripts, to see after what event those messages appear ?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer - although I'm just guessing - is that there's some debug code hidden away that uses opera.postError() to insert messages in the error console.

Try disabling User JavaScripts / extensions, even browser.js..?